# Pessoal como eu posso fazer para quando eu clicar invés de trocar o número inserir mais 1 número, como uma calculadora por exemplo

Tags: javascript

```
var b1=[]
var b2=[]
var b3=[]
var b4=[]
var b5=[]
var b6=[]
var b7=[]

function botao1() {
   b1=1
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b1

    
}
function botao2(){
   b2=2
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b2

}
function botao3() {
    b3=3
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b3
}
function botao4() {
    b4=4
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b4

}
function botao5() {
   
    b5=5
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b5
}
function botao6() {
    b6=6
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b6
}
function botao7() {
      b7=7
     document.getElementById('resultado').innerText=b7
}

function res() {
    if (b1+b6==17) {document.getElementById('candidato').innerHTML='bolsonaro'
        
    }
}

function soma() {
  
}
```

Comment: Tente `innerText+=...`

Answer (score -1):

Javascript é uma linguagem fracamente tipada, então quando você define uma variável da seguinte forma: b1=1; b7=7; essas variáveis estarão recebendo um valor de tipo numérico.

O que você deseja fazer em seu caso, é realizar uma concatenação entre duas strings e compará-las com outra string.

Tente realizar desta forma:

```js
var b1=[]
var b2=[]
var b3=[]
var b4=[]
var b5=[]
var b6=[]
var b7=[]

function botao1() {
   b1='1'
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b1

    
}
function botao2(){
   b2='2'
   document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b2

}
function botao3() {
    b3='3'
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b3
}
function botao4() {
    b4='4'
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b4

}
function botao5() {
   
    b5='5'
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b5
}
function botao6() {
    b6='6'
    document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=b6
}
function botao7() {
      b7='7'
     document.getElementById('resultado').innerText=b7
}

function res() {
    if (b1+b6=='17') {document.getElementById('candidato').innerHTML='bolsonaro'
        
    }
}

function soma() {
  
}
```